# Search posts in a Fan Page with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's simple how can I search a post in Facebook with the API Facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=logo&type=post
```

This query retrieve all public posts which contain the word "logo". But, how could I search a post in a specific Fan page? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

**Alternative Solution:**

I have thought of a hybrid solution: I can get all the posts with that query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=object_id&limit=25&type=post&q=logo

and through php to restrict only those belonging to specific Fan Page. Although I have a question, over what period of time the search is done?

What do you think?

Comment: how about searching in returned result using regex ?

Comment: It's a solution, but what about performance? It's not possible do it with a API query?

Comment: see my answer. by the way, regex is fast, if you make it right.

Comment: yes, I see your answer, :). You mean that it's not possible with API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search in posts in page, use this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id_here/search?q=keyword_here&type=post
```

Comment: This query returns: "category", "name" and "id" of the Fan Page, but not the info post.

Comment: Whats more, always return the same data, whatever "q" you put

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution:

I have thought of a solution hybrid: I can get all the posts with that query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=object_id&limit=25&type=post&q=logo

and through php to restrict only those belonging to specific Fan Page. Although I have a question, over what period of time the search is done?

What do you think?